# Why Eigen's sample codes tend to use <float> class?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to use Eigen in C++ for matrix manipulation.

It looks like I can choose float or double type for real numbers,
such as Eigen::Matrix4f or Eigen::Matrix4d.

In normal C++ code, I guess double is more popular nowadays than float.

However, in Eigen's documentation, float seems to be more frequently used than double.

Is there any special reason???

I know this is very immature question but I need help......
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float` is usually faster. Performance makes a lot of sense for math.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It cleared my problem, thanks.